# Twilio client js status busy/cancelled no fired

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I'm using the Twilio client js in my browser in order to make calls.
In the server I build the Twiml:

```
const dial = twiml.dial({
            /*action: `http://270311bb.ngrok.io/twilio/callend`,*/
            callerId: availableNum.phoneNumber || availableNumbers[0].phoneNumber
        }, (n) => {
            n.number(request.body.number, {
                statusCallback: `http://270311bb.ngrok.io/twilio/${request.body.agentId}/status`
            });
        });
```

I also tried with the 'action' parameter.
In my status/callend route I get the callstatus only as completed or no-answer, even if the called number is busy, or not connected.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`StatusCallbackEvent`'s that you can receive from a call are only initiated, ringing, answered, or completed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event). Busy or not connected calls are also completed calls. Can you try querying the call from the API when you receive the completed event and see what status the actual call in.